# How to write references in a Report and Research paper?

Tags: publications, research-process, citations

I am about to submit my master's thesis **report** and writing a **research paper** along with it to submit in CHI conference. While writing I got stuck when I had to mention the references. Here, I have few questions for while referencing the material in the report and research paper.

1. How to add a research paper references in the end of the report as
   well as in the research paper? Basically I am asking the format of
   reference. There are so many format and I don't know which one to
   use.
2. How to add a website references in the end of the report and
   research paper? Again I am asking the format.
3. How to mention these references in the paper or report? What I mean by this is how to include these references inside the report and research paper?

I have read couple of papers and I am extremely confused what to use where
   and how.

**EDIT:-** I forgot to mention here that I also wanted to reference the images I used in the report or research paper. I am not sure but can we reference the images as weblink. Also how to mention the images with reference in the middle of the text?

Comment: Look at how other theses do it, ask your supervisor, other students that are somewhat ahead, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most conferences with peer-reviewed proceedings specify a particular format for their papers.  Among other things, such a format generally constrains you to a particular manner of presenting references, answering all of the questions that you have.  To find this information, you typically need to find the call for papers and then look down near the end somewhere in the submission instructions, where there will typically be a link to a standard format specification.  Most will provide both a Word template and a LaTeX template, as well as a PDF example of what things should look like.

CHI is no different, and their formats for this year may be found at [this link](https://chi2016.acm.org/wp/guide-to-submission-formats/).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Jakebeal's answer, get a few papers from the same journal (ideally in a field near yours). That might give hints on how to handle e.g. discussion of previous work (how much detail), and other such non-explicit rules.